# How can I store 4 8 bit coordinates into one integer (C#)?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, 32bit-64bit

Lets say I have the following four variables: player1X, player1Y, player2X, player2Y. These have, for example, respectively the following values: 5, 10, 20, 12. Each of these values is 8 bits at max and I want to store them into one integer (32 bits), how can I achieve this?

By doing this, I want to create a dictionary, keeping count of how often certain states have happened in the game. For example, 5, 10, 20, 12 is one state, 6, 10, 20, 12 would be another.

Comment: is there a specific reason why you don't want to use the `byte` type? Or maybe you weren't aware of this type?

Comment: That sounds a bit like a homework, so I will not answer the question directly but instead ask you another question which might help you: using pen & paper, how would you store four decimal numbers in the range from 0 to 99 within one single decimal number with 8 decimal places? how would you extract them back?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BitConverter`

To get one Integer out of 4 bytes:

```
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { player1X, player1Y, player2X, player2Y }, 0);
```

To get the four bytes out of the integer:

```
byte[] fourBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

To "squeeze" 4 8 bits value in a 32 bit space, you need to "shift" the bits for your various values, and add them together.

The opposite operations is to "unshift" and use some modulo to get the individual numbers you need.

Comment: ow, BitConverter does that for you already, just refer to [Paul Sütterlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62372534/479251)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alterantive:

Make a struct with defined packing. Expose:

- The int32 and all 4 bytes at the same time
- Make sure the apcking overlaps (i.e. int starts at 0, byte variables at 0, 1,2,3

Done.

And you can easily access and work with them WITHOUT a bitconverter et al and never have to define an array, which is expensive jsut to throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the values by shifting to the apropriate offset

Example:

```cs
// Composing
byte x1 = ...;
byte x2 = ...;
byte x3 = ...;
byte x4 = ...;

uint x = x1 | (x2 << 0x8) | (x3 << 0x10) | (x4 << 0x18);

// Decomposing
uint x = ...;

byte x1 = x & 0xFF;
byte x2 = (x >> 0x8) & 0xFF;
byte x3 = (x >> 0x10) & 0xFF;
byte x4 = (x >> 0x18) & 0xFF;
```